# Angular 2 router : I want to pass a parameter in the route but the result is not true

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to pass a parameter in the route but the result is not true : 
 component.html

```
  <md-card class="card" (click)="onSelect(survey)">
```

component.ts

```
public onSelect(sur:Survey) {
     let id:string;
     console.log("what i want to send :", sur.id);
     id = sur.id;
     this.router.navigate(['/vote', id]);   }
```

AppRouter.ts

```
 {path: 'vote/:id', component: childComponent} ];
```

childCompnent.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
     this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       let id =+params['id'];
       console.log(" the result ", id);
     });   }
```

the resulet :

- what i want to send : 2016-06-30-aa1
- the result : 48

Comment: Where do `2016-06-30-aa1` and `48` come from?

Comment: come from component.ts i use a array contain object  and i use `*ngfor` for display the list of object and now i need to pass the id of selected object to an other component , `48`  i don't now where sh'is come , sh'is look generated automatically

Comment: this part: `let id =+params['id'];`, notice that the id is a string, and you are casting it to be a number via `+`. Try to remove that `+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is 
in the child component we don't need to the + operation

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       let id =params['id'];
       console.log(" the result ", id);
     });   }
```

in the main component 
we just identify the parameter asses is an id

```
>  this.router.navigate(['/vote', {id:sur.id}]);
```